# WCF Error in deserializing body of request message for operation

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, serialization, wcf-binding

I have a asp.net client web application and a WCF web service which was developed from schema xsd. When calling the service i get an error in deserializing body of request. I tried updating service reference but that did not help.

This is my code:

```
OSEOP.HMA_OrderingBindingClient client = new OSEOP.HMA_OrderingBindingClient();

OSEOP.GetCapabilitiesRequest request = new OSEOP.GetCapabilitiesRequest();
request.GetCapabilities = new OSEOP.GetCapabilities();
request.GetCapabilities.service = "OS";

string[] arrAcceptedVersions = { "1.0.0", "2.0.0" };
request.GetCapabilities.AcceptVersions = arrAcceptedVersions;

OSEOP.Capabilities capabilities = client.GetCapabilities(request.GetCapabilities);


txtGetCapabilitiesResponse.Text = capabilities.Contents.ToString();

client.Close();
```

and this is the error:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1 was unhandled by user code
  Message=Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetCapabilities'.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
       at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at OSEOP.HMA_OrderingBinding.GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request)
       at OSEOP.HMA_OrderingBindingClient.OSEOP.HMA_OrderingBinding.GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\oseop_testclient\023fa9f5\ea876945\App_WebReferences.k9c5tqe1.0.cs:line 44135
       at OSEOP.HMA_OrderingBindingClient.GetCapabilities(GetCapabilities GetCapabilities1) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\oseop_testclient\023fa9f5\ea876945\App_WebReferences.k9c5tqe1.0.cs:line 44141
       at _Default.cmdGetCapabilities_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Documents\DEV\SARPilot\SVN_repository\Services\OrderingServices\TestClient\Default.aspx.cs:line 30
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

as you can see, the error happens at the client and never gets sent out to the WCF service. For this reason i'm not getting anything in my MessageLogging. That's why i thought it would have something to do with the service reference.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT #1:**
What i don't understand is the GetCapabilities takes a GetCapabilitiesRequest parameter but when i'm implementing the client, my intellisense asks for a OSEOP.GetCapabilities object.

OSEOP is what i named the web reference.

```
public class OrderingService : HMA_OrderingBinding
{
    public GetCapabilitiesResponse GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/oseop/1.0", ConfigurationName = "HMA_OrderingBinding")]
public interface HMA_OrderingBinding
{
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute]
    GetCapabilitiesResponse GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request);
}



/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "3.0.4506.2152")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/oseop/1.0")]
public partial class Capabilities : CapabilitiesBaseType
{

    private OrderingServiceContentsType contentsField;

    private NotificationProducerMetadataPropertyType notificationsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public OrderingServiceContentsType Contents
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contentsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.contentsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public NotificationProducerMetadataPropertyType Notifications
    {
        get
        {
            return this.notificationsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.notificationsField = value;
        }
    }
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped = false)]
public partial class GetCapabilitiesRequest
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/oseop/1.0", Order = 0)]
    public GetCapabilities GetCapabilities;

    public GetCapabilitiesRequest()
    {
    }

    public GetCapabilitiesRequest(GetCapabilities GetCapabilities)
    {
        this.GetCapabilities = GetCapabilities;
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2** @Marc:
Marc, your answer was very helpful. But you see how the server side is something like this:

```
GetCapabilitiesResponse GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request)
```

Yet my intellisense thinks it's something like this:

```
Capabilities GetCapabilities(GetCapabilities GetCapabilities1)
```

And I've found a snippet of code within the IOrder.cs file (47,256 lines of code generated from schema) that I'm sure is causing the problem but I tried commenting out the trouble function, updating service reference, and my intellisense **still wants GetCapabilities GetCapabilities1**

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
public partial class HMA_OrderingBindingClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<HMA_OrderingBinding>, HMA_OrderingBinding
{

    public HMA_OrderingBindingClient()
    {
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    GetCapabilitiesResponse HMA_OrderingBinding.GetCapabilities(GetCapabilitiesRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetCapabilities(request);
    }

    public Capabilities GetCapabilities(GetCapabilities GetCapabilities1)
    {
        GetCapabilitiesRequest inValue = new GetCapabilitiesRequest();
        inValue.GetCapabilities = GetCapabilities1;
        GetCapabilitiesResponse retVal = ((HMA_OrderingBinding)(this)).GetCapabilities(inValue);
        return retVal.Capabilities;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two questions:

1. Why do you create a `GetCapabilitiesRequest` object which contains a subobject `GetCapabilities`, and then in your method call, you only use the contained suboject `GetCapabilities`??

   So why not just create the `GetCapabilities` in the first place and forget about the wrapping object??
2. Also, can you please **show** us the `GetCapabilitiesRequest` and `GetCapabilities` and the return class `Capabilities`, too? If you have a deserialization error, most likely something with those classes isn't right...

**Update:** thanks for the update to your question....
hmm... can't seem to find anything obviously wrong at first glance....

About your question:

> What I don't understand is the
>   `GetCapabilities` takes a
>   `GetCapabilitiesRequest` parameter but
>   when I'm implementing the client, my
>   intellisense asks for a
>   `OSEOP.GetCapabilities` object.

Yes, that's clear - your **service-side** uses its set of classes - `GetCapabilitiesRequest` and so forth.

When you do an `Add Service Reference` in Visual Studio, what VS does is

- interrogate the server to find out about the service - what methods it has and what parameters it needs
- it creates a set of **copies** of your classes for the client-side proxy - in that namespace that you define on the `Add Service Reference` dialog box. Those are classes that look exactly the same as your server side classes - but they are **not** the same classes - they just serialize to XML (and deserialize from XML) the same way as those on the server. That's why your client-side proxy has different classes in a different namespace. That's standard WCF behavior - nothing to be alarmed about...

**Update no. 2**: Carlos, the schema you sent me seems to be incomplete or has errors. Try to use [OGC project on CodePlex](http://ogc.codeplex.com) as a base and build in your code manually or wait until the schema gets ‘officially’ published.

Comment: 1: the GetCapabilitiesRequest and all that code was created with the svcutil tool. I wish i understood why, but i had no say in it. I agree, it makes no sense and i would have done it differently.
2:I will post and edit to show you the GetCapabilitiesRequest and so on.

Comment: Please check my Edit on the question.

Comment: @capdragon: answered at least one of your questions (hopefully!)

Comment: Thanks for your explenations, i made another edit (just for you).